# CSS not loaded R shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I have created a simple shiny app. Previously it was working fine, but since a couple of weeks, whenever I access it using the browser, it seems that the theme (or any CSS) is not loaded. The whole page is plain text, and interactivity is absent.

However, if I manually refresh the webpage from my browser, the theme is correctly loaded, and the app works as intended.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyvalidate)
library(shinyFeedback)
library(shinyToastify)
library(shinythemes)

ui = fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
  tags$head(tags$script("Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('mymessage', function(message) { window.location = message;});")),
  verticalLayout(
    titlePanel(div(column(width = 6, offset = 3, h3("My app")), 
                   column(width = 1, offset = 0, tags$img(src = "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/bird-colorful-gradient-design-vector_343694-2506.jpg", width = "100"))),
               windowTitle="My app"
    ),
    useShinyFeedback(),
    useShinyToastify(),
    mainPanel(
      div(column(width = 6, 
                 offset = 6,
                 style = "padding-bottom:10px",
                 h5("Please complete the fields below."),
                 "After clicking on 'Submit', you will be redirected to one of the three websites.")
      ),
      div(column(width = 6, 
                 offset = 6,
                 style = "padding-bottom:10px",
                 "If you have any question, don't hesitate to get in touch with us at", tags$a("mail@mail.com", href = "mail@mail.com"), ".")
      ),
      div(column(width = 6,
                 offset = 6,
                 style = "padding-bottom:10px",
                 "We must check you understood.",
                 checkboxInput("eligible", "Yes, I have.", FALSE),
      )
      ),
      div(column(width = 6,
                 offset = 6,
                 style = "padding-bottom:10px",
                 "Sure?",
                 checkboxInput("consent", "Sure.", FALSE),
                 actionButton("submit", "Submit"),
      )
      ),
      div(column(width = 6, 
                 offset = 6,
                 style = "color:white; background-color: #002046",
                 textOutput("random1")
      )
      )
    )
  )
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  session$onSessionEnded(stopApp)
  
  # validate
  iv <- InputValidator$new()
  iv$add_rule("eligible",
              sv_equal(TRUE, 
                       message_fmt = "All the fields are mandatory."))
  iv$add_rule("consent",
              sv_equal(TRUE, 
                       message_fmt = "All the fields are mandatory."))
  iv$enable()
  
  # submit
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    if(iv$is_valid()) {
      showToast(
        session, 
        input, 
        text = "You will be shortly redirected to your website.", 
        type = "success"
      )
      allocation <- sample(c("https://www.google.com", 
                             "https://www.starbucks.com", 
                             "https://www.burgerking.co.uk"), 
                           1, 
                           replace = F)
      output$allocation <- renderText({paste(allocation)})
      output$random1 <- renderText({
        paste0("You have been redirected to ", allocation, ".")
      })
      session$sendCustomMessage("mymessage", allocation)
    } else {
      showToast(
        session, input, 
        text = "Some inputs are not valid.", type = "error"
      )
    }
  }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is it something to do with the code or with shinyapps.io? If the latter, is it due to a setting (i.e. I can change it) or more like an issue on their side?